# How to handle the background to foreground thing in android for all activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Actually I am connecting with my application server each and every time when my application is coming from background to foreground for checking the session validity no matter on which activity user is currently on.

So What I did I have created one boolean type preference and setting up it true in to onCreate() method of activity and checking it on onResume() if it is true that means the application is coming from onCreate() which indicate the first time launch of activity so I am not running the set of code for validation and at the same time I am setting up that preference as false .

So if the application is coming from background to foreground the code will execute and check the validation of session.

But I feel it very messy when I am adding activities to my application each and every activity i need to take care of all these stuff not feeling it as a standard way of doing the same. Is there any function provided in Android which can help me out and fulfill my requirement ?

If not what should I do in the code level so I need not to worry about all these thing while adding the activities in my application means suggest some good way to achieving the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider creating a BaseActivity that will handle all the initialization and checking stuff that all activities should do. Now let all your activities extend the BaseActivity, instead of directly extending `Activity`.

This way if you'll need to add a new activity, the only thing you'll have to do will be to extend BaseActivity.

Comment: ok I thought the same but if all my activities having some other stuff too on onResume except validation can i keep that as it is in the activities overriding of onresume will not make default onresume in BaseActivity noneffective ?

Comment: Remember onCreate() method calls `super.onCreate()`, onResume() calls `super.onResume()` and so on. Using `super` you are able to access superclass members. With other words, the current activity will invoke the methods defined in `BaseActivity`. So yes, you can add additional functionality in onResume() in your concrete activities without worrying that onResume() in BaseActivity will become noneffective.